# struts if tag in display table tag

Tags: struts2, struts

trying following code inside display tag.

```
     <s:if test="%{#percentid} == '12'">
                        <display:column title="Status">Fail</display:column>
                    </s:if>  <s:else>
       <display:column title="Status">pass</display:column>
       </s:else>

and in java action class code 
list.add(new ViewWork(percentid));
```

i not getting value of in if tag. i tried different condition in if tag
please help me
thanks in advance

Comment: Check the code We need to use %{#attr.ViewWork.percentid=='12'} or try %{#attr.ViewWork.percentid==12}(Without ' symbol)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use:

```
<display:table uid="myTable" ... other attributes>
  <display:column title="Status">
    <s:if test="%{#attr.myTable.percentid == '12'}">Fail</s:if>
    <s:else>Pass</s:else>
  </display:column>
</display:table>
```

The key is to use `#attr.[uid from display:table].percentid`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how we do in display:table

```
    <display:table id="ViewWork" name="ListName" pagesize="5"  requestURI="ActionName" style="text-align:center; font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', helvetica, arial, serif; max-width:100%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" class="table footable">
<display:column title="percentid"><s:if test="%{#attr.ViewWork.percentid=='12'}"><display:column title="Status">Fail</display:column></s:if><s:else><display:column title="Status">Pass</display:column></display:column>
</display:table>
```